JSON Deserialisation returning null for a list in a list c#
I currently have a JSON File where the data is represented as:
{
    "ClientAddress": [
        {
            "firstLine": "123 road one",
            "city": "London"
        },
        {
            "firstLine": "456 road two",
            "city": "Los Angeles"
        }
    ],
    "ClientAddress": [
        {
            "firstLine": "92 kings road",
            "city": "Dublin"
        },
        {
            "firstLine": "34a Jim Road",
            "city": "New York"
        }
    ]
}

As I try to run this through my deserialiser, I have a return count of 4 but each object is null. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong with the mapping.
The following is my C# file:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonData = "{\"ClientAddress\":[{\"firstLine\":\"123roadone\",\"city\":\"London\"},{\"firstLine\":\"456roadtwo\",\"city\":\"LosAngeles\"}],\"ClientAddress\":[{\"firstLine\":\"92kingsroad\",\"city\":\"Dublin\"},{\"firstLine\":\"34aJimRoad\",\"city\":\"NewYork\"}]}";

            var resultSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressRequest>(jsonData);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class AddressRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("ClientAddress")]
        public List<ClientAddress> ClientAddress { get; set; }
    }

    class ClientAddress
    {
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

    class Address
    {
        [JsonProperty("firstLine")]
        public string FirstLine { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}


That kind of JSON structure  would need to be parsed manually rather than deserialised, as it doesn’t map naturally to a C# class - each instance of ClientAddress contains a list of ‘un-named’ objects. You could parse the Json using JObject.Parse(json) and then manually create the model by reading the child tokens.

Not a valid JSON, according to JsonLint. You can't have 2 same key in a JSON object.

Change public List<ClientAddress> ClientAddress { get; set; } to public List<Address> ClientAddress { get; set; }. The class ClientAddress can be removed

See working example https://dotnetfiddle.net/dEbd0V

@YongShun You are right and Newtonsoft says "I don‘t care" ;o)

Just to confirm, your root JSON object really has two duplicate properties both named "ClientAddress"?  Because, while JSON with duplicate property names is not malformed, it is discouraged.  From rfc8259: When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable...

Also, do you need to re-serialize with duplicate property names?

Your problem description and your code don't fit together ...  "return count of 4"  What does that even mean? What "return count" are you speaking of? Furthermore there is no Addresses property in your JSON. What's supposed to be serialized into that object? And finally, even if you get the typing right: You have duplicate keys ClientAddress in your root object. That's highly discouraged, because the results are unpredictable ...

It's quite hard to achieve your goal with just implementing custom JsonConverter. We need to dig deeper and implement customization at reader level. Luckily, there is already similair question, which we can use. Here is explanation How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object
We need wonderful method DeserializeAndCombineDuplicates implemented there:
public static JToken DeserializeAndCombineDuplicates(JsonTextReader reader)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
    {
        reader.Read();
    }

    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        reader.Read();
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            string propName = (string)reader.Value;
            reader.Read();
            JToken newValue = DeserializeAndCombineDuplicates(reader);

            JToken existingValue = obj[propName];
            if (existingValue == null)
            {
                obj.Add(new JProperty(propName, newValue));
            }
            else if (existingValue.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                CombineWithArray((JArray)existingValue, newValue);
            }
            else // Convert existing non-array property value to an array
            {
                JProperty prop = (JProperty)existingValue.Parent;
                JArray array = new JArray();
                prop.Value = array;
                array.Add(existingValue);
                CombineWithArray(array, newValue);
            }

            reader.Read();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
    {
        reader.Read();
        JArray array = new JArray();
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            array.Add(DeserializeAndCombineDuplicates(reader));
            reader.Read();
        }
        return array;
    }

    return new JValue(reader.Value);
}

private static void CombineWithArray(JArray array, JToken value)
{
    if (value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (JToken child in value.Children())
            array.Add(child);
    }
    else
    {
        array.Add(value);
    }
}

For that to work fully, we need to update our classes a little to match property names in JSON (changes were only applied to ClientAddresses):
public class ClientAddresses
{
    public List<Address> ClientAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [JsonProperty("firstLine")]
    public string FirstLine { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}

Now we can use it as:
var jsonData = "{\"ClientAddress\":[{\"firstLine\":\"123roadone\",\"city\":\"London\"},{\"firstLine\":\"456roadtwo\",\"city\":\"LosAngeles\"}],\"ClientAddress\":[{\"firstLine\":\"92kingsroad\",\"city\":\"Dublin\"},{\"firstLine\":\"34aJimRoad\",\"city\":\"NewYork\"}]}";
using var sr = new StringReader(jsonData);
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
var token = DeserializeAndCombineDuplicates(reader);
var addresses = token.ToObject<ClientAddresses>();

